# Only back up when connected to power and only within time window

Tags: backup, scheduling

I make daily backups using Deja Dup (the standard backup application of Ubuntu) on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. Creating a backup takes a lot of power which is why I only want a backup to be automatically started if my laptop is connected to power.

Furthermore, I don't want a backup to be automatically started from 8:00 to 9:45 (24 h system) local time (which is CET/CEST).

Lastly, I don't want more than one backup per day to be created automatically but want backups to be created automatically if possible. I don't care whether a backup having been manually started manually is regarded.

A backup can be initiated using the command

```
deja-dup --backup
```

, however, I'd like it to be done with minimum priority so other applications aren't slowed down by it, so that'd be:

```
nice -n 19 deja-dup --backup
```

Of course, other means of making Deja Dup start a backup are also acceptable.

I *could*, of course, force my way to a solution, by writing a program or script doing exactly what I want. However, it's Linux and there probably an easier and more elegant way. I guess it will probably still result in a script but it can probably be much shorter and more elegant than what I would come up with when forcing my way to a solution. But please don't play golf with this one. :D

Comment: systemd.unit(8) can be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now basically took a giant sledge hammer killed the problem by writing a script.

First, install the PHP command line interface, e.g. via

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

I'm assuming PHP 7 is installed. If you use PHP 5, remove `: int` from `determineTimeUntilBackup()`'s method header.

Then, save the following script I wrote (which comes with absolutely no warranty and isn't tested but I have a good feeling about it and was only slightly drunk when writing it (right before posting this answer)) to a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// CONFIGURATION
/**
* The command to execute to create a backup.
*/
define('backupCommand', 'nice -n 19 deja-dup --backup');

/**
* The minumem period of time between 2 backups in seconds.
*/
define('minimumBackupSeparation', 20*3600);

/**
* The minimum time between 2 checks of whether a backup should be created in
* seconds. Only positive integers are permitted.
*/
define('minimumWaitingTime', 300);

/**
* The path of the file in which the time stamp of the lasted back is stored.
*/
define('latestBackupTimestampFile', 'latestBackupTimestamp');
// END OF CONFIGURATION


// Checking for root.
if(posix_getuid() == 0) {
    die('Backup script runs as root. This is probably a bad idea. Aborting.'."\n");
}

if(minimumWaitingTime !== (int) minimumWaitingTime) {
    die('Configuration error: Minumem waiting time must be an int!'."\n");
}

if(minimumWaitingTime < 1) {
    die('Configuration error: Minimum waiting time too small!'."\n");
}


while(true) {
    $timeUntilNextBackup = determineTimeUntilBackup();

    if($timeUntilNextBackup === 0) {
        createBackup();
        continue;
    }

    if($timeUntilNextBackup < 0) {
        $timeUntilNextBackup = minimumWaitingTime;
    }

    sleep($timeUntilNextBackup);
}


/**
* Returns a non-negative int when waiting for a point in time, a negative int
* otherwise. If a backups should have been created at a point in the past,
* `0` is returned.
*/
function determineTimeUntilBackup() : int {
    $latestBackup = 0;

    if(file_exists(latestBackupTimestampFile)) {
        $fileContents = file_get_contents(latestBackupTimestampFile);
        if($fileContents != (int) $fileContents) {
            die('Error: The latest backup timestamp file unexpectedly doesn\'t '
                    .'contain a timestamp.'."\n");
        }

        $latestBackup = (int) $fileContents;
    }

    $idealTimeUntilNextBackup = $latestBackup + minimumBackupSeparation - time();
    if($idealTimeUntilNextBackup < 0) {
        $idealTimeUntilNextBackup = 0;
    }

    $batteryStateReading = exec("upower -i `upower -e | grep 'BAT'` | grep 'state'");
    if(empty($batteryStateReading)) {
        echo 'Unable to read battery state!'."\n";
    } else {        
        if(strpos($batteryStateReading, 'discharging') !== false) {
            // Not connected to power.
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return $idealTimeUntilNextBackup;
}


/**
* Creates a backup and notes it in the latest backup timestamp file.
*/
function createBackup() {
    file_put_contents(latestBackupTimestampFile, time());
    exec(backupCommand);
}
```

Make the file executable, e.g. via:

```
chmod 755 backup.php
```

Then, add the file to the startup applications. How this is done depends on your distro. For Ubuntu, open "Startup Applications" from the dash and create a new entry. As the command, simply enter the path the the file you created above.

I did not add support for the restriction on the time of the day as my personal circumstance requiring this doesn't exist any more but it can easily be added.

---

Edit: I noticed that the battery reports to be discharging all the time if my laptop has been connected to power for several days, causing the script to create no backups until I disconnect my laptop from power for several minutes and the reconnect it.

To solve this problem, it now doesn't read whether the battery reports to be charging or discharging but instead reads the state of the power adapter:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// CONFIGURATION
/**
* The command to execute to create a backup.
*/
define('backupCommand', 'nice -n 19 deja-dup --backup');

/**
* The minumem period of time between 2 backups in seconds.
*/
define('minimumBackupSeparation', 20*3600);

/**
* The minimum time between 2 checks of whether a backup should be created in
* seconds. Only positive integers are permitted.
*/
define('minimumWaitingTime', 300);

/**
* The path of the file in which the time stamp of the lasted back is stored.
*/
define('latestBackupTimestampFile', 'latestBackupTimestamp');
// END OF CONFIGURATION


// Checking for root.
if(posix_getuid() == 0) {
    die('Backup script runs as root. This is probably a bad idea. Aborting.'."\n");
}

if(minimumWaitingTime !== (int) minimumWaitingTime) {
    die('Configuration error: Minumem waiting time must be an int!'."\n");
}

if(minimumWaitingTime < 1) {
    die('Configuration error: Minimum waiting time too small!'."\n");
}

// Don't back up within 5 minutes after bootup.
sleep(5*60);

while(true) {
    $timeUntilNextBackup = determineTimeUntilBackup();
    echo $timeUntilNextBackup."\n";

    if($timeUntilNextBackup === 0) {
        createBackup();
        continue;
    }

    if($timeUntilNextBackup < 0) {
        $timeUntilNextBackup = minimumWaitingTime;
    }

    sleep($timeUntilNextBackup);
}


/**
* Returns a non-negative int when waiting for a point in time, a negative int
* otherwise. If a backups should have been created at a point in the past,
* `0` is returned.
*/
function determineTimeUntilBackup() : int {
    $latestBackup = 0;

    if(file_exists(latestBackupTimestampFile)) {
        $fileContents = file_get_contents(latestBackupTimestampFile);
        if($fileContents != (int) $fileContents) {
            die('Error: The latest backup timestamp file unexpectedly doesn\'t '
                    .'contain a timestamp.'."\n");
        }

        $latestBackup = (int) $fileContents;
    }

    $idealTimeUntilNextBackup = $latestBackup + minimumBackupSeparation - time();
    if($idealTimeUntilNextBackup < 0) {
        $idealTimeUntilNextBackup = 0;
    }

    $batteryStateReading = exec("acpi -a");
        if(strpos($batteryStateReading, 'on-line') === false) {
            // Not connected to power.
            return -1;
        }


    return $idealTimeUntilNextBackup;
}


/**
* Creates a backup and notes it in the latest backup timestamp file.
*/
function createBackup() {
    file_put_contents(latestBackupTimestampFile, time());
    exec(backupCommand);
}
```

You will, however, need `acpi`:

```
sudo apt install acpi
```

Comment: Can this script detect change of ac line during execution of backup? You start back up i.e at 20:00 with ac power present, but after a minute ac power goes off. Does it get it?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou No, it doesn't. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to accomplish this. If a backup is due but the laptop isn't connected to power, the script always sleeps for a predefined period of time (I chose 5 minutes but it's defined as a constant in the top of the file so it has a name and can easily be adapted to personal preference) and checks again.

Comment: I think i found a way to catch the change in ac power supply...

Comment: to avoid too much comments, we can talk here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53211/george

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution i can think of is to set up a crontab that can be adjusted to run once per day your back up script also in a particular time frame.

For the "connected to power" check, this command works in my case:

```
root@debian:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests# upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC |grep online
    online:              yes
```

You could include this on your script like this:

```
onpower=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC |grep online |awk -F " " '{print $NF}')
if [[ "$onpower" == "yes" ]];then 
deja-dup --backup
fi
```

Comment: @UTF-8 Is this answer helpfull for you? I'm not sure what you mean by writting "I don't want a backup to be automatically started from 8:00 to 9:45".  You want to exlude this time period?

Comment: I'm sorry, I somehow missed that you posted this answer. No, it doesn't because it wouldn't back up if my laptop isn't connected to power at the time the cron job is executed but becomes connected to power a minute later.

Comment: @UTF-8 Sorry, i missed your point.... There is a way to detect if you run on battery or not. All you have to do is to set up cron to call a script that will execute your back up if AC power is present. Something like "if AC connected then backup else interupt back up".

Comment: @UTF-8 There is a kind of difficulty to keep continuous tracking of AC power presence, i admit...We miss something like a kind of "event"

Comment: On my laptop, the variable always contains an empty string.

Comment: @UTF-8 What is the output of this command? `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC`

Comment: If you're interested in how to do it in a more general way, see my answer.